# Auto upload files in included path using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a NetBeans javascript project with several included paths for plugins.  I do not want to include the plugins in my core repository, so I have created separate, external folders for each and am including them via an include path.  Because I test across many devices, I need my changes to upload on save and this works fine for the main code base, however, I would like to be able to edit a plugin via the include path and see those changes auto uploaded as well.  Is this possible?

As of right now, the only alternative I see is to create separate projects for each plugin, which I am willing to do if this is the only option.  The single project workflow is very preferable to me and I might be willing to switch IDE's if this is possible in another environment.

I would be happy to elaborate if my intentions are unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. What about creating one single "umbrella" project for all plugins and simply manage it the same way you do the main project?

Personal note: What you have is basically several projects and the uploading is focused always on single project. So what you want is like "I want to treat them as projects but not to at the same time" :) Btw, how do you edit a plugin? I guess open it as a project in NetBeans or use some text editor. So again you basically treat it as a project.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right about that after some research of my own.  Good suggestion.  I'm working on plugins for a javascript framework, not neatbeans.  Sorry I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Even JS plugins can be treated as projects in NetBeans. I created a "PHP project with existing sources" and pointed to folder with my JS project files and it works fine :)